# "kiun" instead of "kion" as direct object pronoun

Tags: correlatives, pronouns

I just stumbled upon this sentence taken from a 1974 textbook on Esperanto published in Poland:

"Andreo kaj Mary promenis en la parko kaj dividis impresojn pri la bonega spektaklo, **kiun** ili partoprenis en la operejo."

And I cannot understand why there is *kiun* and not *kion*. It clearly refers to *spektaklo*, it is not used as a determiner, but as pronoun. And *spektaklo* is not a person but a thing. Is it an error or is there another exceptional rule governing the use of "kiu" and "kio" in Esperanto?

Comment: Welcome to [esperanto.SE] Stack Exchange! I'll have to look there more thoroughly, but https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies & its subchapters seem to imply that "kiu" is the default pronoun to introduce a relative subclause, while "kio" as a relative pronoun is only used when the conditions for certain rules that mandate "kio" instead of "kiu" are fulfilled.

Comment: I'm not that fluent in Esperanto. All I managed to auto-translate says something about "more abstract meaning of nouns". This doesn't explain anything. When the meaning of noun becomes "more abstract"? And what about relative clauses? There's an example "Mi volas, ke tio, kion mi diris, estu vera". Does it mean if I talk about abstract things, I should say "tio, kion mi diras", and when I talk about non-abstract things, it should be "tiu, kiu mi diras"? OK, but where the border after which what I'm saying becomes abstract enough to use "kio"? And isn't Esperanto becoming overcomplicated here?

Answer (score 4):

## *kio*

Das-g mentioned a [chapter of PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies/) that explains the differences between relative *kio* and *kiu*. The subchapter about *kio* lists four main cases when *kio* is used.

### 1. when referring to a correlative ending to *-o*

● *Mi volas, ke **tio, kion** mi diris, estu vera.*

Note that this correlative can also be implicit.

● *Oni ricevas, **kion** oni bezonas. = Oni ricevas **tion, kion** oni bezonas.*

### 2. when a noun is left out

● *La sola, **kion** mi deziras, estas… = La sola afero, kiun mi deziras, estas…*

### 3. when referring to a whole clause

This causes the following distinction:

● *Julio Cezaro venkis la pontanojn kaj gajnis gloron, **kio** estis surprizo.*

● *Julio Cezaro venkis la pontanojn kaj gajnis gloron, **kiu** estis surprizo.*

where *kio* refers to the whole preceeding clause and thereby the surprice was the victory and the glory following it. In the latter case *kiu* refers only to the glory and thereby the surprice was only it (even in the meaning that the surprice was the form of glory, a titel, a triumph, or some other reward).

Unfortunately this distinction is not observed by all.

### 4. when referring to an object of the same type

● *Ili alvenis per aŭto, **kion** mi ankoraŭ ne havas, sed ja planas aĉeti.*

Here *aŭto* does not refer to any specific car, but cars in general. If there were *kiu*, you would be planning to buy just that car.

## *kiu*

As the last example above shows, the basic meaning of *kiu* is "one of a known set".

In your example

*…pri la bonega **spektaklo, kiun** ili…*

the set can be thought to be all *spektakloj* and the relative pronoun *kiun* in the subclause refers to the one identified as the one in which Andreo and Mary participated in.

Note, that if no set is given, it is supposed to be "people, humans", and this meaning is used in questions:

- *Kiuj promenis en la parko?*

Comment: Your answer does not make it clearer. I'm not a native speaker of English, so you'd need to explain, how do you understand "which". As I remember "which", as a relative pronoun, refers to objects, and its counterpart for people is "who". But "kiu"/"kio" distinction has nothing or very little to do with "person"/"non-person" difference. So, please never ever explain Esperanto function words. It rearely explains anything. And you haven't answered why "kio" is wrong there. Unless you mean "kio" refers to whole clauses, while "kiu" to words and phrases. Am I right?

Comment: I am sorry that my answer was not clear. The key phrase is the "one of a known set". In order to illustrate that I rewrote my answer to cover all cases of _kio_.  PS. Neither am I a native speaker of English.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `kiun` is correct, and `kion` less so. `kion` is not necessarily referencing `spektaklo` as with `tio, kion`, but more of the main phrase. Like *what* in:

> ..., kio estis la unua paŝo de interrilato.

`kiu` meaning *which* (adjective) can only reference `spektaklo`. Like in:

> pri tiu spektaklo, kiun ...

However this is linguistics on an advanced level. More congruent to some European languages.